# Java Swing: How to allow user enter Jtextfield again when wrong input?

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a **math quiz game** where the questions are generated randomly, and user has to ***fill in the answer in the jtextfield***. Then, when the user press ***enter button*** to *check answer*, the *next question* will also load in the same form (displayed in the jlabel) for **10 rounds**.

But I'm having a problem where I'm using the for loop (to keep generating the questions and prompt user answer for 10 rounds) that it does ***not*** allow user to enter answer in textfield after the first question.  It skips the gettext() from jtextfield and repeats empty textfield message as the textfield is left blank. Same goes for the repeated catch numberformatexception message when other input than numbers are entered. 
How do I make the gui  ***get user input in the textfield again*** for each round for incorrect input?

I have gone through similar tags here and I have tried reading on threads for solution as some suggest in those, but I'm really new to it so I would really appreciate the help. If there is a simple solution than that, I would really love to hear it cause I have been stuck for so long. Thank you so much.

Here is the code:

Variables

```
double answer=0; //correct answer

double playerans=0d;
String ans;

String mOperation, question;
int no1, no2;
int rounds = 10;
public Game() {
    initComponents();
    this.EasyQuestion(); 
}
```

**Enter button** //the problem

```
    private void enterbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   //needs to get user fill textfield then load next question
   for (int i=0; i<rounds; ++i)
  {

    roundlabel.setText(" " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
    boolean valid=false; 

    ans = ansfield.getText().trim(); 
    if (!ansfield.getText().equals(""))
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                playerans = Double.parseDouble(ans); //convert to double
            //check player answer- if (Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(answer) - q.answer) <= 0.01) 
            valid = true;

            }catch (NumberFormatException e){ //other input other than integers
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter number only");
                ansfield.setText("");
                valid = false;
                //thread sleep
            }
        } while (!valid);

       if (Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(ans) - this.answer)  <= 0.01) {//for correct answer

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got it right!"); //mesage to inform player

        }
        else //wrong answers
        {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got it wrong!"); //mesage to inform player

        }

    }
    else
    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty field");//
    } 

   //generate next question
    EasyQuestion();

    /*open end game form 
    this.close();
    EndGame end = new EndGame();
    end.setVisible(true);
            */
   }//end for

}
```

Math Question generated

```
//generate math question for easy level
public double EasyQuestion() 
{
    //call method to generate random integers 
    no1 = this.createNum(100); //set range to 100
    no2 = this.createNum(100); 

    //generate random 4 math operations

    int math = createNum (4);
    switch (math){
        case 0: 
            mOperation= "+";
            this.answer = no1 + no2;
            break;

       case 1:
            mOperation = "-";
            this.answer = this.no1 - this.no2;
            break;

        case 2:
            mOperation = "*";
            this.answer = this.no1 * this.no2;
            break;

       default: 
           mOperation = "/";
           //to prevent math error
           while (no2 == 0) {
            this.no2 = this.createNum(100);
            }
           this.answer = 1.0 * this.no1 /this.no2; //to make double num type
           break;

    }
    //display questions
    question =  (no1 + " " + mOperation + " " + no2 + " =  ?");
    qlabel.setText(question);
    ansfield.setText("");
    return this.answer;
}

//generate random number for math integers
public int createNum (int range)
{
    //create instance class Random
    Random rand = new Random();
    int generate = rand.nextInt(range);

    return generate;
}
```

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Answer (score 1):

This is not how event-driven programs work, and what you're trying to do is to shoe-horn linear console programming into an event-driven GUI. The loop in fact is blocking the Swing event thread (the "Event Dispatch Thread or EDT), and this can render your program frozen and useless.

Instead, make your program more event-driven and more "stateful" where it changes how it responds to events based on the state of key "state" fields/variables.

In this situation, you could present the user with 10 JTextFields and ask them to enter data into the fields, and not allow further actions until all fields are filled with appropriate data -- for instance have a "submit" JButton which is disabled, give the JTextFields a DocumentListener that checks content any time a document is changed, and that only enables the submit button once all inputs are valid.

Or you could have an int counter variable, an array of String and a single JTextField, and each time the user submits text, increment the counter and put the String into an appropriate position in the array (or ArrayList)...

In this situation, you'd probably have a non-GUI Question class, one that holds a single question text and its answer. You'd then create a `List<Question>` questions = new ArrayList<>();` and then using the index int field that I described above, in the ActionListener, accept the input and then advance to displaying next question and display it, again getting rid of the for loop entirely.

Most importantly though, you need to leave linear programming mode and get into the event-driven mindset.

---

For example:

In the following program, I keep track of which question I am asking with an int state field called `index`. In the ActionListener, I check if the answer is correct, I then advance the index field via `index++`. I then check if there are more question's left by comparing index to the questions array list's `size()` property,.....

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleQuestions extends JPanel {
    private List<Question> questions;
    private JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("   ");
    private JTextField answerField = new JTextField(20);
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    private int index = 0;

    public MultipleQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;

        ActionListener listener = e -> submitListener();
        submitButton.addActionListener(listener);
        answerField.addActionListener(listener);
        submitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

        questionLabel.setText(questions.get(index).getQuestion());

        JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel();
        questionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Question"));
        questionPanel.add(questionLabel);

        JPanel resultPanel = new JPanel();
        resultPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Result"));
        resultPanel.add(resultLabel);

        JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();
        answerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Answer"));
        answerPanel.add(answerField);
        answerPanel.add(submitButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(questionPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(resultPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(answerPanel);
    }

    private void submitListener() {
        String answerText = answerField.getText().trim();
        if (answerText.equals(questions.get(index).getAnswer())) {
            resultLabel.setText("Correct");
        } else {
            resultLabel.setText("incorrect");
        }
        answerField.selectAll();
        answerField.requestFocusInWindow();

        index++;
        if (index >= questions.size()) {
            resultLabel.setText("All Done");
            submitButton.setEnabled(false);
            answerField.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            questionLabel.setText(questions.get(index).getQuestion());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Question> questions = Arrays.asList(
            new Question("What is 1 + 1", "2"),
            new Question("What is 1 + 2", "3"),
            new Question("What is 1 + 3", "4"),
            new Question("What is 1 + 4", "5"),
            new Question("What is 1 + 5", "6"),
            new Question("What is 1 + 6", "7")          
        );

        MultipleQuestions multipleQuestions = new MultipleQuestions(questions);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mult Q's");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(multipleQuestions);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

```
class Question {
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public Question(String question, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;       
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, its the first time Im attempting in gui from cli math quiz I did, so it makes sense as I would assume it works the same way, so thank you for the explanation. I could see how the next questions keep generated through the counter. But how would I apply the numberformat exception as mine generates randomly without set answer like the example for when other input than integers are entered? I tried through keyreleased jtextfield for example to avoid the do while loop, but then it would not accept negative integers.

Comment: @taera that's a separate issue -- one question per question on this site. Your original question though has been solved

Comment: oh sorry, but I did mention the "repeated numberformatexception" in the question as well. I noticed that in your example, it basically does not allow user to try and enter correct answer again? It just skip to next question. My problem was that I wanted to allow user enter correct answer again when wrong input where I used the for loop (but wrong to use for event driven as you kindly explained). In that case, how do I allow user to enter correct answer again in gui? thank you

Comment: @taera: ***again*** please no multi-part questions, they are not allowed. You need to ask a separate question, but really you should first isolate the numberformatexception problem in a smaller program and try to fix it yourself. If you remain stuck, then ask a question on this site on *that* problem, but understand that this issue has been addressed and answered many times previously on this site, and so you will want to review prior similar questions. You simply would put that sort of logic in the actionlistener where it gets the input. You validate it and don't increment further until valid

Comment: I'm really sorry, I wasn't aware of that. I mentioned them both because it was due to the same single problem, which is how to get user input again when wrong. I have actually gone through similar tags and hesitated to ask but I really needed the explanation. So I apologise if its too much, thank you so much for your help and advice ^ ^